# How to get the value of an asp:TextBox element nested in a jQuery Typeahead Search <div> using .NET

Tags: jquery, vb.net, typeahead.js, typeahead

I have the following markup

```
<div class="typeahead__container">
  <div class="typeahead__field">
    <span class="typeahead__query">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="searchInputField" CssClass="js-typeahead" name="q" type="search"></asp:TextBox>
        </span>
    <span class="typeahead__button">
            <button type="submit">
                <span class="typeahead__search-icon"></span>
    </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Typically, using code behind we can get the text value of the `<asp:TextBox>` element as follows:

```
Dim val As String = searchInputField.Text
```

In my case, this does not work.

The above code is part of the example Hockey v2 of the following demo
http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/

I assume I am not able to get the Text value(s) since the results are not plain text within the textbox (see the following figure)

### [image]

The following image depicts the way the text values are rendered in the HTML. The values are stored within `<span>` elements, so the `<asp:TextBox>` is not aware of these values.

### [image]

Any suggestions please on how to get the Text values (Canadiens and Avalance) using code behind (or using any other approach in general)?

## UPDATE - SOLVED

Thank to the suggestion of [@Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115360/andrew-morton) I managed to pass the value to the back end using an `<asp:HiddenField>` element using the onSubmit Callback of Typehead.

```
callback: {
        onSubmit: function (node, form, items, event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         var searchValue = items.map(a => a.ID)
         document.getElementById("hiddenSearchResults").value = searchValue ;
         setTimeout(function () { __doPostBack(document.forms[0].name ); }, 1)
}
```

Then in the code behind I got the value like this:

```
searchValues = hiddenSearchResults.Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the rendered Id of the input element will not be "searchInputField" - have a look at the page source in a browser.

However, you can add `ClientIdMode="Static"` to the control's properties to make it so:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="searchInputField" ClientIdMode="Static" CssClass="js-typeahead" name="q" type="search"></asp:TextBox>
```

and then the jQuery will be able to find it.

To then get the data in the code-behind, I suggest adding an asp:hidden control and populating that on the JavaScript onclick event for the button. The value of the hidden control will then be available server-side.

Comment: That's true, indeed, but actually the issue persists. If I create a second `<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="searchInputField2"></asp:TextBox>` out of the `<div>` elements , even without the **ClientIdMode="Static"** declaration I am able to get the value of the TextBox.

Comment: @GrigoriosKoulouras I added a suggestion on how to get the data to the server.

Comment: I still can't get the Text value of the asp:TextBox. I'm pretty sure that the issue is a result of the modification of the textbox by the Typehead and the way this library stores the values within the input control (asp:TextBox in my case). I realised that the values are stored into <span> elements which are created automatically by .js code of the Typehead library. Also, if I type some characters and press the 'search' button before completing the search process, I am able to get the Text in the back end (with the usual way).

Comment: Does the typeahead code have some function which returns the value? Otherwise you will need to extract the text from those spans.

Comment: I slightly changed the description in the main thread. Does this make sense now?

Comment: If the data is not going into the asp:TextBox then it appears to me that you can use the [`resultContainer`](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/documentation/) property in the typeahead code's constructor to put it into a different container, like an asp:Hidden control.